# Storm-R integration

Tags: r, apache-storm

I am trying to integrate my R script with Storm. The code for my Rbolt is:

```
public class RBolt  extends ShellBolt implements IRichBolt {
public RBolt() {
    super("Rscript", "storm_OR.R");
}
@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
    outputFieldsDeclarer.declare(new Fields("OR"));
}

@Override
public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
    Config ret = new Config();
    ret.setMaxTaskParallelism(1);
    return ret;
}
}
```

I am getting the following error. Any help? I have made sure that the path variables have path of R and Rscript.

```
17469 [Thread-12-__system] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Preparing bolt __system:(-1)
17474 [Thread-12-__system] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt __system:(-1)
17480 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loading executor RBolt:[1 1]
17483 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loaded executor tasks RBolt:[1 1]
17491 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Finished loading executor RBolt:[1 1]
17491 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Launching receive-thread for 8d8a13de-5e87-4e14-b2c2-59b4dfc070c6:1027
17493 [Thread-14-RBolt] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Preparing bolt RBolt:(1)
17496 [Thread-15-worker-receiver-thread-0] INFO  backtype.storm.messaging.loader - Starting receive-thread: [stormId: EventProcessing-1-1457335172, port: 1027, thread-id: 0 ]
17500 [Thread-14-RBolt] INFO  backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess - Storm multilang serializer: backtype.storm.multilang.JsonSerializer
17510 [Thread-14-RBolt] ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error when launching multilang subprocess

    at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.launch(ShellProcess.java:64) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt.prepare(ShellBolt.java:99) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5641$fn__5653.invoke(executor.clj:690) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__457.invoke(util.clj:429) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript" (in directory "/tmp/933c85f3-f5b5-4a60-b342-7d4969b43d46/supervisor/stormdist/EventProcessing-1-1457335172/resources"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

This directory in tmp folder does not exist and is created on the fly. Any suggestions please.

**UPDATE: Resolved this by creating another resources folder in the resources folder of the project such that the jar has a resources folder with the R script in it.**

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of "shell" components is to start as an independent process, therefore your script needs to implement [multilang protocol](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Multilang-protocol.html).
Alternatively you can find a library that implements the protocol and has R integration, like [FsStorm](https://fsstorm.github.io/FsStorm/): it implements multilang and you can call R functions via [R type provider](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/).